# reading binary values stored in text using verilog

Tags: verilog

I am working on project in which I have to read 5 bits binary values from text file. I have to read each 5 bit binary number and then assign them to 5 different 1 bit registers one by one. Moreover i can't use 'memreadb' because my text file is so huge almost 2mb and I think 'memreadb' can't deal with such a huge file because its not working in my case. so can anyone please tell me how to use 'fopen' and 'fread' function to solve my problem because i have not work on file handling in Verilog till now. And can anyone provide me an example similar to my problem?

Thanks,

Sami

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$fscanf` to read your file one line at a time.

```
integer status, fd;
reg [4:0] value;

initial begin
   fd = $fopen("data_file.dat", "r");
   if (!fd) $error("could not read file");
   while (!$feof(fd)) begin
         status = $fscanf(fd,"%b",value);
         // check status, then do what you need to do with value
   end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. i'm trying to display value in status by using this statement: "$display("%b",status);" but it is not displaying me my original data stored in file...

Comment: Look up $fscanf in the 1800-2017 LRM

Comment: sorry I didn't get you... what is 1800-2017 LRM?